# Android/Java: How to import classes in a subpackage from another sub-package?

Tags: java, android, class, package, subclass

First of all I'm not sure if this is Android specific, I have two packages with a subclass and I'm trying to import one subclass from the other subclass which doesn't seem to work. This has never occurred to me before, am I not supposed to do this?

Here you can see the error, "Exercise" cannot be resolved, yet I have tried to import it but that doesn't seem to work either.

[image: error package]
[image: cannot resolve]

All good when I move class "Exercise" into package "database".

[image: good package]
[image: good]

Comment: Are you importing it? `import sub.models.Exercise;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your `Exercise` class declaration. If it is declared this way:

```
class Exercise {...}
```

You will never be able to import it because this is called *package declaration* which means that you only can declare it if you are in it's package. Do you understand? That's why when you move the class to the `DatabaseQuery` package, it works fine.

But if the declaration of your class is something like:

```
public class Exercise {...}
```

Then you need to check your environment, clean caches or restart your IDE.

Comment: Thank you, invalidate/restart showed me the cause of the problem (stupid renaming problem that I caused myself).